# I have troubles making a while loop in python

Tags: python, list, while-loop

I have been meaning to make a program where u can add items to it until you type a certain command so it stopes this is my code( an absolute beginner in coding and in English)

Comment: Show us your attempts, and the specific problem you encountered. We can't tell you how to solve a problem we haven't seen -- [mre] guidelines are good place to start; also see [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 0):

You could use a **[set](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#sets)** of strings that contain the possible inputs that can stop the program:

```py
QUIT_INPUTS = {'quit', 'q'}


def main() -> None:
    print('Deadly Carrot\'s Python Item Input Program')
    print('=========================================')
    items = []
    user_input = input('Enter an item or quit: ')
    while user_input.lower() not in QUIT_INPUTS:
        items.append(user_input)
        user_input = input('Enter an item or quit: ')
    if not items:
        print('You entered 0 items...')
    else:
        print(f'You entered {len(items)} items:')
        print('\n'.join(items))
    print('Goodbye!')


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

**Example Usage 1:**

```
Deadly Carrot's Python Item Input Program
=========================================
Enter an item or quit: Apple
Enter an item or quit: Banana
Enter an item or quit: Carrot
Enter an item or quit: Quit
You entered 3 items:
Apple
Banana
Carrot
Goodbye!
```

**Example Usage 2:**

```
Deadly Carrot's Python Item Input Program
=========================================
Enter an item or quit: q
You entered 0 items...
Goodbye!
```

Answer (score -1):

I can't see your code.

```
go = ""
while go != "stop":
    go = input("Type:")
    print(go)
```

Something like this?

Comment: See the _Answer Well-Asked Questions_ section of [How To Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer). Questions that are not specified in enough detail to allow certainty as to which answers correctly address them should not be answered at all.